# Three.js - problems smooth shading a Lambert material on custom geometry

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl, shader

I have created a custom geometry in Three.js. Now, I would like to create a mesh that uses a smooth-shaded Lambert material. Using a loop, I have created the array of vertices, then faces, and afterwards I have called

```
geometry.computeCentroids();
geometry.computeFaceNormals();
geometry.computeVertexNormals();

var colorMaterial =  new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( {color: 0x0000ff, side: THREE.DoubleSide} );
var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, colorMaterial );
scene.add(mesh);
```

The result is almost perfect, except that it appears as though the material is using `shading: THREE.FlatShading` as seen below:

[image]

while I was expecting the default appearance one normally expects with `shading: THREE.SmoothShading`.  What do I need to add/change to obtain a smooth Lambert shading?

(If it helps, a complete live example is at http://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/Marching-Cubes.html and the geometry and mesh are created around lines 250-280.)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It's because neighboring faces do not share vertices in your model.

If you call `geometry.mergeVertices()` right after you complete the creation of your geometry, and before you call `geometry.computeVertexNormals()`, then your shading will look smoother.

three.js r.58

Comment: Perfect, thanks very much! You deserve a StackOverflow three.js genius badge :)