# Three.js CSG How to change result's material and color?

Tags: javascript, three.js, threecsg

I'd like to get MeshLambertMaterial on this particular object 'result' which I get after making union of two meshes:

```
var lathe = new THREE.Mesh(latheGeometry);
var cube_bsp = new ThreeBSP( lathe );

var box = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 2,30,3);

var sub = new THREE.Mesh( box );
sub.position = new THREE.Vector3(0,0,19);
var substract_bsp  = new ThreeBSP( sub );
var subtract_bsp  = cube_bsp.union( substract_bsp );

var result = subtract_bsp.toMesh(); 
    result.rotation.x = Math.PI * -0.5;
    scene.add(result);
```

Here I have a box and a latheGeometry. After union is done I get random plain color ugly object. Instead I should get LambertMaterial white color object.

Images: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cJzUC.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can apply the material when calling `ThreeBSP.toMesh()`:

`subtract_bsp.toMesh( new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( {color:0xFFFFFF} ) );`

or after the creation on the resulting mesh:

`result.material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( {color:0xFFFFFF} ) );`

Comment: Can I also somehow make changes to resulting mesh and change the amount of segments used for this object? It became very 'sharp': http://prntscr.com/azevq8

Comment: Not that i know of, but this looks like a shading issue. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/17119380/4977165. You can also apply a subdivision modifier: http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_modifier_subdivision.html.

Comment: Hmm, I don't think its shading issue because other renders look just fine. Thanks for your help!